# How to change the position of the table of contents in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

With RStudio and knitr I see that I can add a TOC with the following code in my .rmd file.

```
----------------
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: yes
-----------------
```

However, this places the TOC at the very beginning of the HTML document. Is there a way to move the TOC lower on the page? Say after an introductory paragraph?

I tried to use `__TOC__` and `__FORCETOC__` but it did not change the TOC position.

Comment: What about TOC on the side? http://rpubs.com/stevepowell99/floating-css

Comment: Thank you for the link. His solution is interesting, but I am still curious if I can move the TOC lower in text.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The position of the TOC is fixed in the R Markdown default HTML template. If you want to change its position in the document, you'll need to modify the template:

1. Make a copy of the R Markdown HTML template to use as a starting point. You can find it by running this R command: `system.file("rmd/h/default.html", package="rmarkdown")`
2. Move the `$toc` section to where you want the table of contents to appear.
3. Save the modified template in the same folder as the document you're rendering as e.g. `lowertitle.html`
4. Add `template: lowertitle.html` to the `html_document` settings.

From the standpoint of the template, all of the document's content is an atomic unit, so it might be necessary to put any content you want to appear before the TOC in the template itself.

Comment: Is there a similar way to change the location for word documents?

Comment: @jzadra I don't think there is, but here's the question on SO for that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171676/in-rmarkdown-word-document-how-to-make-table-of-contents-appear-later

Answer (score 4):

You can use JQuery to relocate the TOC to an arbitrary position in the file. Simply insert a heading where you want the TOC to go, and use the ID generated by rendering the R Markdown file. For example:

```
<script>
  // Move TOC to the Table of Contents heading (with id "table-of-contents")
  $(function() {
    $( "#TOC" ).insertAfter( $( "#table-of-contents" ) );
  });
</script>
```

A heading called "Table of Contents" somewhere in the R Markdown file will receive id "table-of-contents". The TOC has id "TOC". The Jquery bit above selects that TOC, and inserts it after the "Table of contents" heading, wherever in the document it's located.

Comment: Note that this won't be picked up if the file is rendered on github due to their security protocols

Answer (score 1):

I tried the proposed solutions and although they seem simple enough I could not achieve either. I found an easier solution by @gadenbuie in GitHub:
https://gist.github.com/gadenbuie/c83e078bf8c81b035e32c3fc0cf04ee8

You just need to copy and paste a function to render your TOC in your Rmarkdown file, and then recall it in a chunk where you want your TOC to appear. Therefore, you can recall your TOC wherever you want it in the Rmarkdown file.

If you need further explanation, you can check out @gadenbuie's blog:
https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/add-a-generated-table-of-contents-anywhere-in-rmarkdown/

Answer (score 0):

You could add something in a header which will come after title and before toc, e.g. a yaml header like:

[image]

And then add whatever paragraph or figures to the file header.md that you want.

As an example, I set this YAML up in the README of [brshallo/piececor](https://github.com/brshallo/piececor) so that I could have my 'lifecycle' badge show-up prior to my table of contents.