# How to add title to R markdown TOC

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to add a title to the TOC generated by an R markdown document.

Specifically, I have something like this now:

```
---
title: "The Rebel Base Locations"
author: "Darth Vader"
date: "A long time ago in a galaxy far far away"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: custom.css
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
---
```

What I want is the TOC to have a header called "Contents". I was able to push it to the left using some css.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new field right before the table of contents in the html template. Following [this instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587773/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown), do this:

1. Copy the html template to your .rmd file and change the `$toc$` field to something like this:

```
$if(toc)$
<div id="$idprefix$TOC">
<h1 class="toctitle">$toctitle$</h1>
$toc$
</div>
$endif$
```

2. Then, add the `toctitle`  and `template` fields to your RMarkdown file. For example:

```
toctitle: "Contents"
output: 
  html_document:
    template: toctitle.html
    css: custom.css
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
```

This should add the title before your TOC. You can do other modifications, e.g. change from `h1` to another tag and/or use the field class on the CSS. If you have problems for not using the default template (mathjax won't work), you can change the default style, not adding `totctitle` to a different rmd file later shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Mox, this almost works except not I get a warning: "MathJax doesn't work with self_contained when not using the rmarkdown "default" template." -- the thing is that I need MathJax!

Comment: If you need MathJax, I think the best option is to edit the original template. This small addition shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: possible when toc_float: true? how