# Table of contents under a tab in R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to make an R Markdown doc with tabs and a table of contents under each tab

Here is my header:

```
---
title: "Palliative/Comfort Care/Hospice Patients Report"
output:
  html_document: 
    toc: true
    toc_floating: true
    theme: "cerulean"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"    
pdf_document: default
---
```

Followed by:

```
# {.tabset}
## tab1
## tab 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the position of the table of contents in rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587773/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown)