# Position of Table of Contents in R Bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I would like to move some preliminary stuff, i.e. abstract and acknowledgments, before the table of contents. By default, the TOC comes right after the title page. I am aware of the solution to include abstract into the YAML header like [so](https://community.rstudio.com/t/bookdown-adding-abstract-before-the-table-of-contents/47149), but that does not seem flexible enough for multiple things to come before the TOC.

Note a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587773/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-table-of-contents-in-rmarkdown), which only refers to HTML.

My current YAML header:

```
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: 
- "Institution" 
- "Name"
date: "September 2020"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    citation_package: natbib
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
toc-depth: 2
secnumdepth: 2
lof: True
lot: True
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: ["references.bib"]
csl: american-political-science-association.csl
geometry: "left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
```

Comment: You can write LaTeX code straight to your Rmarkdown, you can insert table of content with `\tableofcontents` and disable the default one in the YAML.

Comment: Easy solution (if you know Latex well which I do not). Want to write up an answer for the bounty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@broti working from what was given in the comments, I went ahead and implemented this with a quick lorem ipsum example. Hopefully that works for you.

```
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: 
- "Institution" 
- "Name"
date: "September 2020"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: false
    toc_depth: 2
abstract: |
  The text of your abstract.  150 -- 250 words.
keywords:
  - key
  - dictionary
  - word
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
toc-depth: 2
secnumdepth: 2
lof: True
lot: True
csl: american-political-science-association.csl
geometry: "left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm"
---


\tableofcontents

\newpage

# Lorem Ipsum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis malesuada nulla eget nisi viverra, ac sodales metus euismod. Fusce at augue augue. Ut pretium mauris egestas metus vulputate interdum. Etiam vitae scelerisque lectus. Nullam augue sapien, lobortis vel interdum id, tempor quis leo. Curabitur dictum tellus sed velit pellentesque, quis eleifend neque congue. Pellentesque id egestas elit. Fusce cursus, elit lobortis semper ornare, nisi sem tempus risus, a pulvinar diam augue id mi. Suspendisse vel dolor sit amet felis pharetra pulvinar.

Phasellus nec consequat nibh. In sagittis urna et libero consequat, consequat elementum magna fringilla. Morbi magna eros, tincidunt eu vestibulum ut, mollis ac nibh. Vestibulum est purus, consectetur vel iaculis ut, finibus nec nibh. Aliquam diam mauris, tincidunt eu eros id, tempus ornare massa. Curabitur laoreet vel velit non pulvinar. Maecenas in posuere dolor, eu auctor lorem.

Aliquam et nisi vitae orci rhoncus varius commodo id nunc. Phasellus sit amet blandit mi. Cras sagittis risus non leo auctor vehicula. Maecenas commodo cursus tellus facilisis varius. Quisque vitae odio ac eros ultricies scelerisque et ut massa. Duis enim nibh, molestie eget risus eget, malesuada condimentum purus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam posuere egestas nisi, in fringilla neque tincidunt et. Mauris vestibulum ut tellus quis sollicitudin. Donec vitae tellus dui. Sed sit amet leo posuere, lobortis felis eu, ornare nisi. Nam mi ligula, viverra ac libero quis, cursus ornare quam. Phasellus ut ex posuere, euismod mi sit amet, convallis turpis. Cras eros lacus, pulvinar eu lacinia dictum, feugiat ac felis.

Aenean molestie at tortor id rutrum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla cursus faucibus neque finibus rhoncus. Proin vitae tellus vitae tortor vulputate tempus. Nulla nec tempor elit. Nulla facilisi. Sed vel justo felis. Nullam id malesuada mi. Sed est sem, condimentum et eros vel, cursus bibendum magna. Aliquam convallis odio sed nisi tempus lobortis. Quisque sed augue turpis. Vestibulum faucibus tellus ac ullamcorper efficitur. Donec ultricies velit vel lorem mollis consequat. Cras commodo egestas aliquam. Morbi volutpat commodo lorem, gravida tristique nunc ornare in. Maecenas auctor lorem magna, eu finibus enim vestibulum sodales.

Sed a tincidunt orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aenean rhoncus dui sit amet metus rhoncus euismod. Etiam risus arcu, porttitor nec velit sed, imperdiet placerat tortor. Pellentesque at erat congue, cursus nisi ac, varius diam. Ut posuere ac massa vel pulvinar. Proin metus neque, blandit id sapien id, eleifend fringilla tellus. Quisque massa tortor, pretium et massa consequat, laoreet convallis mi. Proin pretium turpis ornare elementum iaculis. Suspendisse pulvinar congue diam quis finibus. Donec at eros vehicula, elementum urna at, ultricies est. Phasellus porttitor tincidunt pharetra.
```

side note: something about the `documentclass: book` item is not functionally working. Hopefully you can work around that.